# How do I fix the type inference error in a Completable transformed using RxLifecycle.bindToLifecycle()?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am using Kotlin and RxJava2. It works fine in other types i.e. Observable etc, but when I am using a Completable type it gives me a type inference error :

```
type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
fun <T> bindToLifecycle(): LifecycleTransformer<T> 
Please specify it explicitly
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
viewModel                                                
    .updateText(returnedText) // the completable method                                  
    .compose(activity.bindToLifecycle())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModel                                                
    .updateText(returnedText) // the completable method                                  
    .compose(activity.bindToLifecycle<Void>())
```

This should work on `Completable`